# RoboActionBarActivity for RoboGuice

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, gradle, roboguice

I use Gradle to add the dependency [org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0b-experimental](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.roboguice/roboguice/3.0b-experimental) to my project.

I found a [post on the issue tracker](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/issues/134), saying that there should be a RoboActionBarActivity class (to replace the ActionBarActivity I use for drawer navigation) in the latest beta. I can find the code on [Github](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/blob/master/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/activity/RoboActionBarActivity.java), but the class isn't in the jar. I found several implementations of the RoboActionBarActivity on the web, but those have other dependencies, and I don't want to resolve them all manually. Is there a way to get this class via Gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the `RoboActionBarActivity` class is provided with the RoboGuice library you can make your own descendant class for `ActionBar` support. Or you can get the [ActionBar4RoboGuice library](https://github.com/Paul-N/ActionBar4RoboGuice), which contains the original `RoboActionBarActivity`, and use it with the latest stable release of RoboGuice.

Comment: Thanks, the ActionBar4RoboGuice library was what i was looking for.